# How to use IF() condition in sequelize(V5)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the requirement like validity expiration check ,it should return True/False based on codition.The related mysql raw query shown below:

```
SELECT (valid_to_date > CURRENT_DATE ) AS is_expired 
FROM   order_deals AS os 
WHERE  order_id=1;
```

Q) How can I convert this using sequelize methods and operators?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do something like this

```
SELECT IF(valid_to_date > CURRENT_DATE,1,0) AS is_expired 
FROM   order_deals AS os 
WHERE  order_id=1;
```

IF valid_to_date > CURRENT_DATE is true, return 1, if not 0.

Case can also provide the same function and it maybe more easy to understand than `IF`.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN valid_to_date > CURRENT_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_expired 
FROM   order_deals AS os 
WHERE  order_id=1;
```